# Next.js GET index request fetches multiple times instead of only once. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I am working with Next.js on a tutorial app and am currently facing a puzzling issue that is stopping from one of my components from rendering. It seems to me that a simple `GET` request for an index page is executing multiple times and I'm not sure why. Below is an outline of the issue.

Context:

I have exactly 1 `Prompt` database collection document in mongo db atlas. My Next.js application is connected to this mongodb cloud instance. The database entry is exactly 1 with no other databases entries. The database document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "65283e66e24b46a5cc3e0063",
    "prompt": "As a software engineer, propose some troubleshooting techniques I can use to debug React/Next.js hydration errors.",
    "tag": "web development",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I have the following `api/prompt/route.js` file with the contents below:

```
import { connectToDb } from "@utils/database";
import Prompt from "@models/prompt";

export const GET = async (req, res) => {

  try {
    await connectToDb();

    const prompts = await Prompt.find({}).populate('creator')
    
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(prompts), {status: 200})
  } catch(error) {
    return new Response('Failed to fetch prompts', {status: 500})
  }
}
```

In its simplified stripped down form I have the following component called `Feed.jsx` which fetches for the Prompt objects on page load and then passes onto a `PromptCardList.jsx` component and then to individual `PromptCard.jsx` component for each one. Because I only have one object, I skipped over `.map` and went straight to fetching the only object in the database with interesting results. Here is the code:

```
'use client';

import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const PromptCard = ({post, handleTagClick, handleEdit, handleDelete}) => {
  console.log(post)

  return (
    <div className="prompt_card">
    </div>
  )
}

const PromptCardList = ({ data, handleTagClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className="mt-16 prompt_layout">
      <PromptCard post={data[0]}/>
    </div>
  )
}

const Feed = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("/api/prompt");
      const data = await response.json();
      setPosts(data);
    };

    fetchPosts();
  }, []);


  return (
    <section className='feed'>
      <PromptCardList data={posts} handleTagClick={{}} handleEdit={{}} handleDelete={{}} />
    </section>
  )
}

export default Feed;
```

I have no idea why (I'm new to Next.js and React). My fetch request executes what seems like a total of 6 times for some reason. If I look at the network tab, it looks like this:

```
Feed.jsx:6 undefined
Feed.jsx:6 undefined
Feed.jsx:6 {_id: '65283e66e24b46a5cc3e0063', prompt: 'As a software engineer, propose some troubleshooti… can use to debug React/Next.js hydration errors.', tag: 'web development', __v: 0}
Feed.jsx:6 {_id: '65283e66e24b46a5cc3e0063', prompt: 'As a software engineer, propose some troubleshooti… can use to debug React/Next.js hydration errors.', tag: 'web development', __v: 0}
Feed.jsx:6 {_id: '65283e66e24b46a5cc3e0063', prompt: 'As a software engineer, propose some troubleshooti… can use to debug React/Next.js hydration errors.', tag: 'web development', __v: 0}
Feed.jsx:6 {_id: '65283e66e24b46a5cc3e0063', prompt: 'As a software engineer, propose some troubleshooti… can use to debug React/Next.js hydration errors.', tag: 'web development', __v: 0}
```

I can't make heads or tails of this. Is there a reason why it would be fetching 6 times or why the first 2 times would be `undefined`? Because the first two results are `undefined` my component breaks. How can I begin to address this? Any leads or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Might be because `useEffect` is called twice in React's [strict mode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development). I'm not sure why it's running 6 times though.

I would recommend checking out [react-query](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/quick-start) for fetching data, it's much better suited for fetching data than doing it manually in a useEffect.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Felix. I switched over to React Query like you recommended and it fixed the bugs so I can render the page, but for some reason it still renders the data twice. I'll need to read up on impure components.